# How can I split a line in 2 by words/characters?

Tags: string, bash, awk, cut, wc

I would like to convert:

```
Hello Hello Hi Hello Hello Hi Hi Hi Hi Hello
```

Into:

```
Hello Hello Hi Hello
Hello Hi Hi Hi Hi Hello
```

I want to split a single line in 2, by having them have the closest amount of characters as possible, without cutting off a word.

I think I can probably do it with `wc -w`, `wc -c`, `cut`, and/or `awk`, but maybe you guys can provide some better ideas!

Comment: This question is cross-posted on AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/603739/how-can-i-split-a-line-in-2-by-words-characters-bash-regex

Comment: This isn't something for regular expressions, at least not pure expressions. You are better off splitting by spaces, counting the overall number of words, and finding the space closest to the middle point of the original string (then replacing it with a newline, obviously). Not sure how friendly awk will be with this, though...

Comment: Hi John, is it against the rules to ask in both locations?
My apologies if it is, but I have done this a few times, it is useful to me since sometimes, it isn't answered in one of the sites, and answered in the other.

Comment: @ericramos1990 It is generally considered a bad thing to do.  See, for example: [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).  One reason is the large potential for wasting the time of those who answer questions.

Comment: My apologies, I will keep it in mind for the future, thanks.

Comment: In this specific case, it doesn't so bad to cross post since the answers were different, and I learned the command `fold`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be a job for `fold`, a handy util to wrap lines:

```
$ s="Hello Hello Hi Hello Hello Hi Hi Hi Hi Hello"
$ fold -w $(( ${#s} / 2 + 1)) -s <<< "$s"
Hello Hello Hi Hello
Hello Hi Hi Hi Hi Hello
```

This uses `fold` to wrap each line to a given length. And how do we calculate the length? Just using `${#variable}` and dividing by 2 (+1 to prevent getting three lines if the length is odd). We then use `-s` to prevent breaking words.

From `man fold`:

```
fold - wrap each input line to fit in specified width

   -s, --spaces
          break at spaces

   -w, --width=WIDTH
          use WIDTH columns instead of 80
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, I will look into fold, I never heard of it!
Out of curiosity is it portable and/or frequent in Linux distros?

Comment: I don't know how portable it is, but for example I could even find it in cygwin. So it looks like it is quite a lot.

Comment: You should be aware that `fold` folds on _bytes_ and not on _characters_.

Comment: No, `fold` folds on screen columns which are neither characters nor bytes (e.g. a tab can be multiple columns and a backspace character will count as -1 column positions). It can fold on bytes if given the `-b` argument, though. `fold` is a core UNIX tool, like grep, sed, tr, etc. so should be available everywhere.

Comment: @EdMorton my point was that `fold` can't handle wide characters. In this respect your statement is false too.

Comment: How is my statement false? The fold man page agrees with what I said, see for example http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?fold.

Comment: @EdMorton: I don't know about this man page. It's a well-known fact that `fold` performs poorly with wide characters or other escape sequences: I found [this](http://gnu-coreutils.7620.n7.nabble.com/fold-and-multibyte-characters-td3141.html) and [this](http://marc.info/?l=coreutils-bug&m=124770616328838&w=2) and [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=721324). You can also try it on your own: `fold -sw2 <<< "éé"`.

Comment: I'm not debating how fold handles wide characters (maybe it has a bug? maybe it was never intended to work on wide characters? idk), I'm just wondering what it was I said that was false. AFAIK any man page for fold will say the same thing I said - that fold works on columns, not characters or bytes, and that as such tabs can span multiple columns and a backspace will subtract 1 from the count.